# How to stop CMake from linking against libstdc++

Tags: cmake

I have a very simple CMakeLists.txt for a C++ project, which builds a shared library:

```
add_library(foo SHARED
    ${HDR_PUBLIC}
    ${SOURCES})
```

When linking the library, CMake automatically uses -lstdc++. How can I stop it from doing this?

Comment: What is exactly that troubles you, which are the consequences you are trying to avoid?

Comment: I can't depend on libstdc++ in the environments where I want to deploy this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_LIBRARIES "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "")
set_target_properties(yourtarget PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```

Source: http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/setting-LINKER-LANGUAGE-still-adds-lstdc-td7581940.html

Comment: 3 - not true. you can use standard c++ includes such as <new> for placement new and <atomic> for atomics. These don't depend on any standard libraries. It's quite possible and even desirable to compile with C++ and link with C, and the way to do that is to use LINKER_LANGUAGE to link with C. It's not a hack.

Answer (score 10):

You can add **-stdlib=libc++** to compiler flags.

Simple example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -v -stdlib=libc++")
add_executable(test main.cpp)
```

Give output:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" ... -o test ... -lc++ ...
```

By default:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -v")
add_executable(test main.cpp)
```

Link to stdc++:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" ... -o test ... -lstdc++ ...
```

**[update]**

If you don't need to link to c++ lib at all - use **'-nodefaultlibs'** as linker flag and **'-nostdinc++'** to compiler flag. You may need to link some default libraries, like **'-lSystem'**.

Comment: Hm. I wonder if you there's a similar option for no stdlib at all. I migrated to a different build system a while ago, but thanks for the answer :)