# is there a way to determine system default stdlib?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang++

some system default to `libstdc++` some default to `libc++`. Is there a uniform way to determine it via command line or cmake?

Comment: You can check this stackoverflow discussion from 5 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058403/how-to-stop-cmake-from-linking-against-libstdc

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. I do not want to disable the default libs, instead, I want to detect what the default stdlib option is.

Comment: The point of that link was not to tell you how to disable the default libs, but to show you how CMake picks which library you're using by default. Wasn't that your question?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the cmake cache and seeing which variable contains what you are looking for?